# PNY 64GB Thumbdrive doesn't work in HP Envy h8-1414

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, usb-flash-drive, usb-2

I bought a 32 GB thumb drive (similar to the one below) and copied my wiki on to it using my [Windows 8 laptop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A813PUI).

I then plugged it into my [HP Envy h8-1414](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/HP+-+ENVY+Desktop+-+10GB+Memory+-+1TB+Hard+Drive/6835567.p?id=1218809260533&skuId=6835567) which has Windows 7 shoe horned onto it.

The drive came up, but as soon as I started to browse deeper than the root directory it froze up, and I couldn't `safely remove` it.  I yanked it, and then when reconnecting the drive it asked me to scan it and this screwed it up completely.  I formatted the drive and it just didn't work at all after that on neither the Envy or the Laptop.

I decided that maybe it was a lemon or something, so I returned the drive and bought a [64GB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007XVRGVA) one that was similar (see below) except the size was larger:

[image: PNY 64GB]

I tried the same process and copied my wiki files over to the new drive using the [the laptop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A813PUI) and then I tried to make it work on the [Envy](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/HP+-+ENVY+Desktop+-+10GB+Memory+-+1TB+Hard+Drive/6835567.p?id=1218809260533&skuId=6835567) and got the exact same problem, except that this time when I plugged the drive back into [the laptop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A813PUI) I was still able to access the files.

Now I just use the wiki on the [thumb drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80DpR.jpg) on [the laptop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A813PUI) and remote in from the [Envy](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/HP+-+ENVY+Desktop+-+10GB+Memory+-+1TB+Hard+Drive/6835567.p?id=1218809260533&skuId=6835567), but I still don't understand why the drive doesn't work on the [Envy](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/HP+-+ENVY+Desktop+-+10GB+Memory+-+1TB+Hard+Drive/6835567.p?id=1218809260533&skuId=6835567).

Comment: Perhaps an AV or other security software is having fits dealing with some file on the drive?

Comment: @Karan Shouldn't it popup a message then?

Comment: No idea if that is really what's happening, but if it is then it's entirely possible that whatever's causing it to choke/freeze is also preventing any popups it might ordinarily have displayed.

Comment: Popups?  No it's just `explorer.exe`, and both computers have the same virus scanner so I doubt that's it.

Comment: ****Crickets Chirping**** Anybody?

Answer (score -1):

I also have a 64 gig flash drive from PNY, I put a bunch of files and pictures on it
using an older laptop with windows XP. All was fine until I tried to retieve files on
an HP / Compaq laptop with windows 7. It continues to work fine with the XP software.

Somehow I might have downloaded a driver from Microsoft for WIN XP, think it was
called "xformat" but it's been a while so the name might not be right. Can't find a
driver for WIN 7 though.

Comment: As written, your answer provides very little useful information. Can you expand it on a bit?